# Why is the ground state degeneracy of the toric code 4?

Tags: condensed-matter, field-theory, topology, geometry, lattice-model

Hi I'm kind of confused about the ground state degeneracy in the toric code model.

The generic ground state of the TCM is a state $|\Omega\rangle$: $A_v |\Omega \rangle = B_p | \Omega \rangle = | \Omega \rangle$

But there can be constructions of a different ground state on a torus: Suppose paths $\gamma_1, \gamma_2$ are two independent closed non-contractile paths on the torus, then $\Pi_{s\in\gamma_1}\sigma^z_s|\Omega\rangle$,$\Pi_{s\in\gamma_2}\sigma^z_s|\Omega\rangle$, $\Pi_{s\in\gamma_1}\sigma^z_s \Pi_{s\in\gamma_2}\sigma^z_s |\Omega\rangle$ are the 3 other ground states that are possible, and hence the total is 4 ground states that are possible for the toric code.

My question: Aren't there more ground states possible that are of the form $\Pi_{s\in\bar{\gamma_1}}\sigma^x_s|\Omega\rangle$, etc. that are also possible? And also of course, their products.

But everywhere I check, the ground state degeneracy is always just 4. What makes these other states not ground states? Or are they somehow the same states stated in a different language? Some clarity on what's going on would be very much appreciated!